# How to disable Chrome element unique-id checking

Tags: unique-id

is it possible to disable chrome checking of dom unique-id element in console?
but i want to disable it using javascript code.

dom unique-id error:

[image: dom unique-id error]

Comment: Is there a reason you can't give the elements unique ID's?

Comment: Also, in the future, please copy-and-paste error messages into your question as text, rather than linking to them. It makes them much easier to see, read, google, etc. :)

Comment: the project is already build by other teams and they're loading all the views and using SammyJS for routing. they just show/hide the pages. the problem is some of the page has the same element that's why they put the same id in it. I just want a quick fix so that I don't have to modify all the pages and js codes affected. Is it possible to disable the chrome checking of DOM unique-id?